# Multiple instructions in switch return statement

Tags: python

I am new to Python. Here is my question:

```
import sys

def main():
        print "option 1) check updates 2) rewrite index 3) ..."
        option = raw_input()
        print "\nthe option: is: " + option
        switch_option(option)

def switch_option (option):
        return {
                1:
#                   print "option is 1",
                   1,
                2: 2

        }.get(option, 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

This program works fine, but if I uncomment `<print "option is 1"`, I get an error.
I get this error:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

What am I missing? I tried adding `<,>` and `<;>`.

Questions:

- How can I include debug statements such as print inside a return statement?
- Is the Python syntax waiting for a certain template in my case?
- Does return accept multiple instructions?
- Does print break the execution flow?

Comment: Python doesn't have a `switch`. This workaround abuse of a dictionary can only handle simple value expressions. Use an `if..elif..else` instead.

Comment: You're calling `switch_option`, but not capturing the return type. And your dictionary has number keys, but you're giving a string

Comment: You should *seriously* consider learning Python 3, Python 2 will reach its official End Of Life some time in 2020. If you _really_ need to learn Python 2 syntax to work on old code, then I strongly advise you to learn Python 3 first.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're trying to put a print statement inside a dictionary

You can print before the return

```
def switch_option (option):
    print "option is %r" ‰ option 
    return {
            1: 1,
            2: 2
    }.get(option, 0)
```

Then you'll need to get that result

```
o = switch_option(option)
```

And yes, python supports multiple return values

Comment: That's what I get for answering on my phone

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't use a `print` statement inside an expression the way you're proposing.  You'd have to answer questions like "when does it get evaluated" that some languages have answers to, but not Python.

That having been said, and especially if you're new to Python but have familiarity with other functional languages, you can create a dictionary that has functions as values.  Here's a way to recast your example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def main():
  print("option 1) check updates 2) rewrite index 3) ...")
  option = input().strip()
  print("the option: is: " + option)
  switch_option(option)

def switch_option (option):
  options = {
    '1': option_one,
    '2': lambda: 2
  }
  f = options[option]
  result = f()
  print("the result is: " + str(result))

def option_one():
  print("option is 1")
  return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```